# Moderator elections on sites that are 30+ days out of beta (election schedule list)

Tags: support, moderators, election

I was led to believe that, now that the moderator election software has been tested on Math SE, sites that are 30 days or more out of beta will be given the chance to have moderator elections. I was wondering what the timing was on this; I'm a pro tem moderator on CS Theory and am looking forward to getting some help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yi Jiang's [Moderator Candidate Statistics](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) page will now auto-update and show what the current elections are as well provide links to last election for each site.

Otherwise, here's the full list:

---

#### 2012

- Sep. 10–25 — [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Sep. 10–25 — [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Aug. 13–28 — [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jul. 23 to Aug. 7 — [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jul. 23 to Aug. 7 — [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jul. 16–31 — [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jul. 16–31 — [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jul. 9–24 — [Mi Yodeya / Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election)
- Jul. 9–24 — [Super User](https://superuser.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jun. 4–19 — [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jun. 4–19 — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3) (*3rd election*)
- May 7–22 — [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Apr. 30 to May 15 — [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/3) (*3rd election*)
- Apr. 24 to May 9 — [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 14–29 — [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Feb. 14–29 — [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 6–21 — [Seasoned Advice / Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Feb. 6–21 — [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jan. 30 to Feb. 14 — [Ask Different / Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jan. 30 to Feb. 14 — [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jan. 30 to Feb. 14 — [Arqade / Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3) (*3rd election*)
- Jan. 23 to Feb. 7 — [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 23 to Feb. 7 — [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jan. 9–24 — [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jan. 9–24 — [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/election/1)

#### 2011

- Nov. 28 to Dec. 13 — [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Nov. 7–22 — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Oct. 17 to Nov. 2 — [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Sep. 26 to Oct. 12 — [Database Adminstrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Sep. 13–29 — [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Sep. 13–29 — [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Aug. 8–24 — [Arqade / Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- Jun. 6–21 — [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/2) (*2nd election*)
- May 31 to Jun. 15 — [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Apr. 26 to May 11 — [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Apr. 18 to May 3 — [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Mar. 28 to Apr. 12 — [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Mar. 14–29 — [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 21 to Mar. 8 — [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 21 to Mar. 8 — [Ask Different / Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 14 to Mar. 1 — [Cross Validated / Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 14 to Mar. 1 — [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 14 to Mar. 1 — [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 7–22 — [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 7–22 — [Seasoned Advice / Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Feb. 7–22 — [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 31 to Feb. 15 — [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 31 to Feb. 15 — [Arqade / Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 31 to Feb. 15 — [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/election/1)
- Jan. 21 to Feb. 5 — [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 21 to Feb. 5 — [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 21 to Feb. 5 — [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/1)
- Jan. 18 to Feb. 2 — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1)
- Jan. 18 to Feb. 2 — [Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/election/1)
- Jan. 18 to Feb. 2 — [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/election/1)

#### 2010

- Dec. 2–17 — [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1)

---

#### Out of Beta, not yet scheduled:

Comment: You're a veritable cornucopia of knowledge.

Comment: What happened to 2013? What's upcoming for 2014?

Answer (score 12):

Moderator elections were put on hold due to the Christmas holidays and limited traffic, so I doubt we can hold SO Inc to the 30 day rule. A little birdie mentioned elections will start as early as next week.

**Due to a this not happening as predicted, I would say the new timeline is 6 - 8 weeks**.

<sub>No information has been provided as to which sites, but I would suspect elections over a 1 - 2 months period were required from that time.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, we don't hold moderator elections until the site has enough of a reputation economy and user base to support an election. This is based on all the data from the historical Stack Exchange elections listed in the other answers here.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/

**So the *guideline* is 90 days from public beta to the first moderator election, but that's a minimum.** It can take much longer than that to generate a base of avid users willing to vote in a moderator election.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Stated another way, there is no reason for us to hold elections when we know they will fail -- that is, not enough nominees, and not enough voters, etc.