# Election timeline for SE 2.0 sites

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, moderators, election

Some of the SE 2.0 sites have had their elections, others are currently electing their moderators. I was wondering if the was a definite timeline on when the other SE 2.0 sites will elect their moderators.

The Moderators *pro tem* here (on gaming.SE) are doing a very good job, I just think it is time they get democratically confirmed, which would strengthen their authority.

Comment: Amusingly, I was just talking about this on [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) (Gaming's chat room) about an hour ago.

Comment: Related, possibly even a duplicate: [Moderator Elections on sites that are 30+ days out of beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74000/moderator-elections-on-sites-that-are-30-days-out-of-beta). It was my intention to keep updating my answer with any new information as it comes in. Currently, there is no information about SE sites other than the ones listed.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Technically, then, if you plan to make that an effective timeline, then a link to that posting would be more of an answer to a request for such a timeline than it would be a comment. ♪

Comment: @Mark I was mostly trying to find out if there was some big (evil?!?) plan in which order the SE2 sites would get their elections. But is seems we find it out only at the moment the elections are started.

Comment: currently that seems to be the case, although we did have some warning that the Trilogy would be after Math.SE and before any other SE election.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/

> There are a lot of public Stack Exchange 2.0 sites that are due for
> moderator elections — but we’re
> starting slowly:
>
> - gamedev.stackexchange.com/election
> - cstheory.stackexchange.com/election
> - programmers.stackexchange.com/election
>
> We’re still refining the election
> process; after these three complete,
> we’ll proceed rolling elections on
> even more public sites.

Comment: I'd say starting with 6 sites at the same time, three of which are the _trilogy_, isn't really going slow at all :) I actually was surprised to see those many sites.

Comment: Maybe we were too tame and peaceful to get our elections first ;-)

Comment: @Fabian - The squeaky wheel gets the grease...

Comment: The nail that sticks up gets hammered down.