# Submitting design elements for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, design

I've been wandering around on Stack Exchange, and many interesting sites lack their own graphics. Those who have, such as [SciFi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) or [Role Playing Games](http://rpg.stackexchange.com), are much more appealing, thus more catchy, so people stay longer on the site. They want to use it more.

So where, and how, can I submit pictures, or even just ideas, for Stack Exchange sites with no specific design? Is there a team working on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sites are given full designs when they graduate from beta—though [the beta/graduated terminology may be changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257652/254929) in the future, and the process could change as well.

In the meantime, you can discuss ideas for any site's design, logos, etc. on the associated Meta site. This is addressed in [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://The%207%20Essential%20Meta%20Questions%20of%20Every%20Beta):

> 6. What should our logo and site design look like?
>
> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out
>   ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and
>   respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff who will actively help come up with site
>   designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as
>   exceptional, we are happy to use it.

Some users [feel that old blog post is not very useful any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/254929):

> In almost every beta, the site design question, for example, gets
>   asked and undergoes a fair bit of discussion even though a probable
>   graduation is too far into the future for this discussion to be
>   useful.

That said, the worst that will happen if you offer input is that it will be ignored. There's no harm in the discussion; be sure to use the search function first to see if there's an existing Q&A on that site to offer your design ideas or comments.

Comment: See also: [How many beta sites can the Stack Exchange design team get graduated per year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257739)

Answer (score 4):

The sites with their own designs are *graduated* sites ([though the name may be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257828/can-we-do-something-about-the-graduated-label)) that have fulfilled certain requirements. Those that do not have the special designs are *beta* sites ([another term that may change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257652/can-we-do-something-about-the-beta-label?lq=1)).

The community team at Stack Exchange makes the call on when a site "graduates" and then the design team figures out what the design will be. However, they do ask for input at the beginning (see an example of this [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community?lq=1)).