# When is the exact point of a website graduation in the new system?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, graduating-sites

I haven’t seen a website graduate in the “old system” so I don’t know how it really worked before, but I’m curious how it works now.
I don’t know when is the exact point when a website is considered as graduated:

- when *Beta* is removed from the title?
- when the new moderator election starts?
- when the moderator election ends?
- when the website gets a new design?
- other ... please specify.

[On Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento), [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) is still listed as *Public Beta,* while its first election has ended.

Comment: Ok. I get it, you don't like the question, but can I get a reason for the downvotes?

Comment: If you've been a pro temp moderator then you should know how the voting works on Meta sites.

Comment: I see two questions here. Please choose one, and focus on it, posting the other as new question.

Comment: @slugster. Apparently I was a bad temp, because I don't know how it works. I would still like an explanation though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard. Fair enough. I edited the post and removed the 'side-question'.

Comment: Cheers, fair question now.

Comment: Not sure it's dupe, but you will find some info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september

Comment: [Here's an old post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157124/146015) that goes into it a bit - it is talking about the differences between SO and Meta.SO. While this meta site does carry its own individual reputation, it's still a meta. Down votes can mean your question/discussion is perfectly fine, but people disagree with you. In any case, I believe the answer that's been tendered before is: a site is graduated when the CM(s) have made the decision and the elected mods have been appointed. Site design then follows at some point when design resources permit.

Comment: @slugster. You can put the part of your comment that starts with "I believe the answer" as ans answer. Seams legit from my point of view. Thanks

Comment: Thanks :) I'll leave it as a comment for now though because I can't (easily/quickly) dig out the relevant reference to validate what I said. In the mean time [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/146015) (*loooong read*) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257317/146015) might be helpful.