# Who do we ask if we want another moderator added during our beta?

Tags: support, beta-sites, pro-tem-moderators

I see from [Moderator elections in beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102760/moderator-elections-in-beta-sites) that it is possible to have additional moderators added during a site's beta. We've recently had a request from an active site member to be added as a moderator since the current three are all in North America and he's in NZ. The existing moderators (of whom I am one) are happy to be joined by a new one, so what email should we send such a request to?

We've been in beta for just under a year, are happy with our community growth, but don't expect to be graduating anytime soon given the area51 evaluation of our beta:

11.7 questions per day
Excellent

80% answered Needs Work

127 avid users, 1,888 total users Okay

1.7 answer ratio Okay

511 visits/day Okay

Comment: Note that once a site reaches 10 q's a day it is considered for graduation, so if the community mods decide that your site is worthy it may graduate soon :)

Answer (score 7):

Are the existing moderators asking for another moderator, are regular users asking for this, or both?  Because if the existing moderators don't want another moderator, you'll need to make a pretty solid case for why they're wrong, which you should do by using your per-site meta to make your case and garner consensus.

If the existing moderators feel they need an additional moderator, they should have easy access to the Stack Overflow Community Managers. They should simply bring the issue up with a CM, and make their case for why they need an additional moderator. If the CMs agree, they'll provide guidance on how to proceed.

Comment: I'm one of the moderators. How do I contact a community moderator?

Comment: @joemurray For immediate feedback, head to the [Teacher's Lounge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4) chat room and say 'staff'. Then @ mention a staff member who is around. Alternatively if you don't need immediate feedback, you can send them an email (ask for the CM group email address in the TL).