# Schedule for moderator elections in 2012

Tags: discussion, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderator elections on sites that are 30+ days out of beta (election schedule list)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74000/moderator-elections-on-sites-that-are-30-days-out-of-beta-election-schedule-li)

Is there a schedule somewhere, when will the moderator election happen in each site?
I usually find out about that when I log in and see announcement that it is just happening on one of the sites. Is there schedule somewhere, so I don't miss voting next time?

Comment: I think it's "when needed, probably at least once a year" but no more precise than that. Before the last one there were quite a few moderators making comments about flag queue size and workload which seemed to hint something might be coming.

Comment: @Flexo As per the users are getting increase day by day, i think it will be twice a year. Next election should be in Oct or November